# No image showing on JFrame when adding image to label

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have written some lines of code that supposed to show the image as a label in the JFrame. Here is the code.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("funny.jpg");

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(image);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(label);
```

Comment: Make `frame.setVisible(true);` the last call you make - Swing is lazy and won't update the UI when it changes, you need to do it yourself (it's an optimisation for performance).  Also, what user15358848 said

Comment: @user15358848  yes, the image can not be loaded, how do I fix this? I can't open it with ImageIO as well.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

As you were prompted in the comments of your question, I think you should take care of ensuring that the file exists in the specified location, and using `getResource` for example.

Other than that, you are not utilizing the image's observer pattern for the `JLabel`. Try setting the `ImageObserver` of the `image` to `label`, like so:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("funny.jpg");

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(image);
image.setImageObserver(label); // <-- Added this line.

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(label);
```

Else, see [the corresponding documentation on `setImageObserver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#setImageObserver-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-).

You can also check [the corresponding tutorials' section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

That happens to be because, as far as I know, `ImageIcon` uses a `MediaTracker` to load the image asynchronously, so when you construct an instance of an `ImageIcon` it will return without first blocking until the image is fully loaded. Setting the `ImageObserver` of the `ImageIcon` will ensure that the `ImageObserver` you supplied will get notified about the state of loading the image when the state changes. The default implementation of `Component` (which is an `ImageObserver`) repaints itself so you will then be able to see the image fully loaded, when it is ready.

As an alternative, you can always use `ImageIO#read` which will block until the image is fully loaded into memory (but it will only return a single *frame* in an animated GIF image for example).

I did not test it though, but that's a problem I encouter very often so I think it should work. If it did or it didn't, let me know.

Comment: [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLabel.html) **implements** `ImageObserver`. It will observe the loading of any `Image` passed to it via an `ImageIcon`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes it will observe it if and only if you call `image.setImageObserver(label);`. Otherwise, the `label.setIcon(image);` is not enough, because it will not check if the supplied `Icon` is an `ImageIcon`. Hence one needs to also call `image.setImageObserver(label);`. If you follow the link on the documentation you can clearly see that the recommended way is using `setImageIcon` along with `setIcon`. And as I said in the answer, `Component` is-an `ImageObserver`. I have to admit though it may not be that clear of a statement, so yes your comment should have been part of the answer